# DNS foward request to our server

Tags: domain-name-system, web-server, hosting

Hello we are hosting here own web site. We got our own DNS server.

I remark that some site whoe are not our web site, direct our Web server and MX records on our  mail server.

It's there a way to prevent this kind of attack ?

I meen :

Suppose i host thoses web sites : with the mx record to

a.com
b.com
c.com
d.com

A web site like

y.com
z.com

foward all there request MX and Web to my server. There is no DNS way to valid the right mx server and the right Web server ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you saying you host *foo.com* and someone else has directed the A and MX records for *bar.com* to your IP? The short answer is no, there's nothing to prevent other sites from pointing traffic to your IP.

If this is seriously bothersome, you would have to look at blocking traffic for *bar.com* at your firewall.